# how to add new value in front of each elements in a list?

Tags: python, list

I have a question about adding new value to existing elements in a list.For example if I have

```
myList = ["0","12","221","3344"]
```

I set a condition where if the length of each element in the list is smaller than 4, the program will add value "0" to the front of the each elements.Perhaps it should look like this

```
newList = ["0000","0012","0221","3344"]
```

For now I already done some example code like below

```
x = ["0","1"]
    if len(x) < 4:
        x.insert(0,"0")
print(x)
```

The output is like this

```
["0","0","1"]
```

I've tried to add/change some line like below

```
x = ["0","1"]
  for i in x:
    if len(i) < 4:
        i.insert(0,"0")
print(x)
```

but I got Error saying

```
'str' object has no attribute 'insert'.
```

Did I missed something here or there are other way to do this?
Thank you for your answer.

Comment: When you use `x.insert()` you're inserting new values into the list x, not into the items inside that list. You'll probably want to replace the items in x one by one with whatever you want their new values to be.

Answer (score 6):

For the particular case of adding 0s at the start of strings, you could use [`zfill`](http://python-reference.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/str/zfill.html):

```
>>> myList = ["0","12","221","3344"]
>>> [x.zfill(4) for x in myList]
['0000', '0012', '0221', '3344']
```

Comment: This is the best solution (under the conditions that the strings are always numeric and the fillvalue is always zero).

Comment: `zfill` can also handle negative and plus symbol accordingly `i.e.)'-350'.zfill(5) ==> '-0350'`

Answer (score 3):

You could use the in-built `map` function to apply a `lambda` function to each item in the list as follows:

```
myList = ['0', '12', '221', '3344']
answer = map(lambda x: '0'*(4-len(x))+x if len(x) < 4 else x, myList)
print(answer)
```

**Output**

```
['0000', '0012', '0221', '3344']
```

Answer (score 3):

With a list comprehension:

```
>>> myList = ["0","12","221","3344","11111111111"]
>>> ['0'*(4 - len(x)) + x for x in myList]
['0000', '0012', '0221', '3344', '11111111111']
```

Note that `'0'*y` is the empty string if y is smaller than zero, I added the last value to `myList` to show this. That's why you don't need an if/else in the comprehension.

edit: `str.rjust` is another option:

```
>>> [x.rjust(4, '0') for x in myList]
['0000', '0012', '0221', '3344', '11111111111']
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution:

```
def paditem(item, length):
    return item + ('0' * (length - len(item))) if len(item) < length else item

def padlist(somelist, length):
    return map(lambda x: paditem(x, length), somelist)

# Test Code:
myList = ["0","12","221","3344"]
results = padlist(myList, 4)
for result in results:
    print result
```